# How to hide the header navigation in boostrap datetimepicker?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-datetimepicker

[image]

How to hide header navigation in [datetimepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) following image. Any one suggest or guide to how to solve this.

my code
HTML

```
<div class="input-append">
    <input type="text" name="start_time" placeholder="00:00 AM/PM" class="input-mini statusTime" value="{$response.start_time}" style="width: 100px;"  />
    <span class="add-on glyphicons clock"><i></i></span>
</div>
```

script

```
  $('.statusTime').datetimepicker({
        format: "HH:ii P",
        showMeridian: true,
        autoclose: true,
        todayBtn: false,
        pickDate: false,
        startView: 1
    });
```

Comment: not sure the link that was added references the correct datetimepicker. Most of the options used are not valid options for that script, and the time selection looks different. If indeed that is the script used, format: "hh:mm A Z" should solve the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try adding this to your css, it's a display none for the elements that you don't want showing

```
.table-condensed thead .picker-switch, .table-condensed thead  .prev, .table-condensed thead .next
{     
     display: none; 
}
```